# Group list by specific key in that list

Tags: python, django

I have the following QuerySet result as a list:

```
<QuerySet [{'answer__question__focus': 'hearing_about_the_event', 'name': 'Facebook', 'count': 1, 'total_salience': 1.0}, {'answer__question__focus': 'hearing_about_the_event', 'name': 'Instagram', 'count': 1, 'total_salience': 1.0}, {'answer__question__focus': 'hearing_about_the_event', 'name': 'friends', 'count': 1, 'total_salience': 1.0}, {'answer__question__focus': 'missing_event_information', 'name': 'Line-up', 'count': 2, 'total_salience': 2.0}, {'answer__question__focus': 'missing_event_information', 'name': 'food', 'count': 1, 'total_salience': 1.0}, {'answer__question__focus': 'reason_for_attending', 'name': 'girlfriend', 'count': 1, 'total_salience': 1.0}, {'answer__question__focus': 'type_of_people_attending', 'name': 'incomes', 'count': 3, 'total_salience': 2.26287645101547}, {'answer__question__focus': 'type_of_people_attending', 'name': 'people', 'count': 1, 'total_salience': 1.0}]>
```

I now attempt to group this result in my Django application by **answer__question__focus** with Python. However, I struggle to get my data in the right order/format. How can I do so in an efficient way?

```
[
    'hearing_about_the_event':  # question.pk
    [
        {
            'name': 'Leonardo Di Caprio',
            'count': 4,
            'salience': 3.434
        },
        {
            'name': 'titanic',
            'count': 5,
            'salience': 1.12
        },
        {
            'name': 'music',
            'count': 3,
            'salience': 1.12
        }
    ],
    'missing_event_information':  # question.pk
    [
        {
            'name': 'Leonardo Di Caprio',
            'count': 5,
            'salience': 1.5
        },
        {
            'name': 'titanic',
            'count': 4,
            'salience': 1.12
        },
        {
            'name': 'music',
            'count': 2,
            'salience': 1.12
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Why is this tagged python?

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't made this clear. I try to so in a Django framework application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of `reduce` and `defaultdict`.

Below code is for python 3.

```py
from functools import reduce
from collections import defaultdict

def aggregate(data, item):
    key = item.pop('answer__question__focus')
    data[key].append(item)
    return data

data = reduce(aggregate,qs, defaultdict(list))
```

Comment: Do you mean `aggregate(qs, defaultdict(list))`. Trying to understand the function.

Comment: No, reduce takes:

-1 A function, which will be given (data, your current item) and which should return some data. This data will be given to your function on the next item.
-2 An array containing items referenced just before.
-Your `data` for your first item.

Comment: What I don't understand in your example is "your_key_here". Maybe I didn't explain good enough what my goal is, but the key should be the values of `answer__question__focus`. So it's basically different keys which I can't know upfront as they differ.

Comment: Okay, got it. I still don't understand the reduce function, however, with your way of using `defaultdict` I found a way to solve it. Maybe could you have a look on my solution if you see anything that could be improved? (see edit above) Thank you for your help!

Comment: After I watched that video here I think I understood now how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKlnR-CB3tk

Basically the same as my for loop, just smoother.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author, in order to move it from the question post)*.

Here is my solution. Thanks to @Julien Kieffer

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for entity in entities:
    question_focus = entity.pop("answer__question__focus")
    d[question_focus].append(entity)
```